# Excessive open connections to Mongos instances

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sharding

We're moving from a single replica set to shards and are experiencing some issues. We have 3 mongos instances, 3 config servers, and 15 data nodes (5  shards with 3 replicas). We're seeing really poor query performance and looking at the mongos instances I'm seeing something like 25k open connections per instance!

For example, I'm seeing log lines like

```
[listener] connection accepted from 10.10.36.122:35098 #521622 (23858 connections now open)
```

and

```
[conn498875] end connection 10.10.36.122:41520 (23695 connections now open)
```

For reference, we have another nearly identical environment that we have not yet moved to sharding which is showing ~250 total open connections.

The application code is using the nodejs driver and is using a connection url that looks something like

`mongodb://mongos0.some.internal.domain:27017,mongos1.some.internal.domain:27017,mongos2.some.internal.domain:27017`

I'm at a bit of a loss for how to track this issue down. Is this not the correct way to connect to mongos?

**EDIT (7/7/18)**

After some experimenting, I found that we were using a `connectTimeoutMS` of  180000 (3 minutes). Removing this value resolved the issue. However, it's still not clear why this configuration works with a standalone replica set, but causes issues when sharding. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: This problem can be caused by continuing to open MongoClient connection pools instead of sharing one throughout the app. How is that handled in your code?

Comment: We do create 1 connection and share it. That code is the same in both the sharded and non-sharded environments I mentioned above.